Serialize Java Map<String, Object> to create dynamic GraphQL payload string
I am building a REST application in Java that needs to dynamically build GraphQL payloads to send to a GraphQL API.
We will receive a String entityType = "MyEntity" and a Map<String, Object> myMap that might look like this:
{
    "blobUrl": "myurl.com",
    "accountId": 12345,
    "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "username"
    }
}

It could have many other keys with values of different types instead, so there is no way I can create a template beforehand that indicates which variables need to be bound.
All that we know about the GraphQL payload ahead of time, is that it will be of this format:
mutation {
    Create%s(%s)
}

With that information, I want to generate the following GraphQL payload:
mutation {
    CreateMyEntity(
        blobUrl: "myurl.com"
        accountId: 12345
        user: {
            id: 4
            name: "username"
        }
    )
}

There are ways I could do this by manually looping through myMap and building the payload with a StringBuilder, but I want to know if there is a better or pre-existing way of doing this.
I have looked all over and haven't found anything that doesn't involve having a template that clearly defines the variables and their types.

@Mr.Polywhirl In GraphQL, keys are not surrounded by quotes, so simply serializing to JSON doesn't address that part. Also GraphQL doesn't use commas after each field like JSON does

I'd keep looking at a json to graphql query converter but maybe a simple approach might be to really convert to pretty-printed json and then do some post processing, i.e. remove any commas at the end of lines (those should be the field separators), remove any double quotes at the start of the line and before the first colon (those should be the ones surrounding field names), and finally remove the outermost curly braces.

I believe you are focused on building the query string yourself.
Here is an example of custom serialization:
Entry point
This contains the main method.
package org.example.graphql;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GraphQLSerializer entitySerializer = new GraphQLMutationSerializer("CreateMyEntity");
        String payload = entitySerializer.serialize(jsonInput);

        System.out.printf("Formatted properly? %b%n", payload.equals(expectedGraphQL));
    }

    private static final String jsonInput = """
            {
                "blobUrl": "myurl.com",
                "accountId": 12345,
                "user": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "username"
                }
            }
            """;

    private static final String expectedGraphQL = """
            mutation {
                CreateMyEntity(
                    blobUrl: "myurl.com"
                    accountId: 12345
                    user: {
                        id: 4
                        name: "username"
                    }
                )
            }
            """.trim();
}

Interface
This is an interface for serialization.
package org.example.graphql;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

public interface GraphQLSerializer {
    String serialize(String jsonInput) throws JsonProcessingException;
}

Implementation
Here is where we parse the JSON and format it.
package org.example.graphql;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class GraphQLMutationSerializer implements GraphQLSerializer {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private final String mutationName;
    private final int indentSize;

    public GraphQLMutationSerializer(String mutationName, int indentSize) {
        this.mutationName = mutationName;
        this.indentSize = indentSize;
    }

    public GraphQLMutationSerializer(String mutationName) {
        this(mutationName, 4);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    public String serialize(String jsonInput) throws JsonProcessingException {
        // Parse the input JSON string into a Map using Jackson
        Map<String, Object> inputMap = objectMapper.readValue(jsonInput, Map.class);

        // Format the body and indentation
        String body = formatBody(inputMap, indentSize, indentSize);
        String indentation = indent(indentSize);

        return String.format("mutation {\n%s%s(\n%s\n%s)\n}", indentation, mutationName, body, indentation);
    }

    private static String formatBody(Map<String, Object> map, int indentSize, int currentIndent) {
        return map.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> String.format(
                        "%s%s: %s",
                        indent(currentIndent + indentSize),
                        entry.getKey(),
                        formatValue(entry.getValue(), indentSize, currentIndent + indentSize)))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }

    private static String formatValue(Object value, int indentSize, int currentIndent) {
        if (value instanceof String) {
            return "\"" + value + "\"";
        } else if (value instanceof Number || value instanceof Boolean) {
            return value.toString();
        } else if (value instanceof Map) {
            return String.format(
                    "{\n%s\n%s}",
                    formatBody((Map<String, Object>) value, indentSize, currentIndent),
                    indent(currentIndent));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported value type: " + value.getClass());
        }
    }

    private static String indent(int level) {
        return " ".repeat(level);
    }
}

